# ModelMapper: Custom PropertyMap throws NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapper within my Spring Boot Application (Java 12) in order to map DatabaseEntities to DTOs which will be used for the REST endpoints.

The Recipe class (Database Entity) contains multiple variables. Some of them have a custom type so that they are able to contain multiple languages. However for the REST endpoint a simple object should be returned that only contains one language. Therefore I have two subclasses: `RecipeENG_DTO` and `RecipeGER_DTO` which both inherit from their superclass `Recipe_DTO`.

> My goal is to map a `Recipe` object to a `RecipeGER_DTO` object

## Java Code

### REST Endpoint

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;


@GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<? extends RecipeName_DTO> getAllRecipes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Iterable<Recipe> recipes = recipeRepository.findAll();
        if (request.getHeader("Accept-Language").equals("de")) {
            return StreamSupport.stream(recipes.spliterator(), false).map(recipe -> modelMapper.map(recipe, RecipeNameGER_DTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else if (request.getHeader("Accept-Language").equals("en")) {
            return StreamSupport.stream(recipes.spliterator(), false).map(recipe -> modelMapper.map(recipe, RecipeNameENG_DTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

### Recipe class

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_name_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private RecipeName recipe_name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "method_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Method method;

    private Time prep_time;
    private Time cook_time;
    private int serves;
    private String image;
    private String source;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "recipe_categories",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private List<Category> categories;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user_id;

    private short access;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Recipe() {
        recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
        categories = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

### RecipeDTO class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Recipe_DTO {

    private Long id;
    private String recipe_name;

    private String method;

    private Time prep_time;
    private Time cook_time;
    private int serves;
    private String image;
    private String source;
    private List<String> categories;
    private String user;

    private short access;

    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

### RecipeENG_DTO class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RecipeENG_DTO extends Recipe_DTO{

    private List<RecipeIngredientENG_DTO> recipeIngredients;

    public RecipeENG_DTO() {
        super();
    }
}
```

### RecipeGER_DTO class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RecipeGER_DTO extends Recipe_DTO {

    private List<RecipeIngredientGER_DTO> recipeIngredients;

    public RecipeGER_DTO() {
        super();
    }
}
```

### AppConfig class (ModelMapper Configuration)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        //modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);


        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<RecipeIngredient, RecipeIngredientGER_DTO>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setIngredient(source.getIngredient().getGer());
                map().setAmount(source.getAmount());
                map().setUnit(source.getUnit().getGer());
                map().setGroup(source.getGroup().getGer());
            }
        });

        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Recipe, RecipeGER_DTO>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setId(source.getId());
                map().setRecipe_name(source.getRecipe_name().getGer());
                map().setMethod(source.getMethod().getGer());
                map().setPrep_time(source.getPrep_time());
                map().setCook_time(source.getCook_time());
                map().setServes(source.getServes());
                map().setImage(source.getImage());
                map().setSource(source.getSource());
                map().setCategories(source.getCategories().stream().map(Category::getGer).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                map().setUser(source.getUser_id().getName());
                map().setAccess(source.getAccess());
                map().setCreatedAt(source.getCreatedAt());
                map().setUpdatedAt(source.getUpdatedAt());
                map().setRecipeIngredients(mapAll(source.getRecipeIngredients(), RecipeIngredientGER_DTO.class));
            }
        });

        return modelMapper;
    }

}
```

### The following mappings cause the NullPointerException

> map().setCategories(source.getCategories().stream().map(Category::getGer).collect(Collectors.toList()));
>
> map().setUser(source.getUser_id().getName());
>
> map().setUser(source.getUser_id().getName());
>
> map().setRecipeIngredients(mapAll(source.getRecipeIngredients(), RecipeIngredientGER_DTO.class));

### Error log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'recipeEndpoints': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'modelMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'modelMapper' defined in class path resource [xyz/gigler/cook/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modelmapper.ModelMapper]: Factory method 'modelMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Failed to configure mappings

1 error
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at xyz.gigler.cook.CookApplication.main(CookApplication.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'modelMapper' defined in class path resource [xyz/gigler/cook/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modelmapper.ModelMapper]: Factory method 'modelMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Failed to configure mappings

1 error
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.modelmapper.ModelMapper]: Factory method 'modelMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Failed to configure mappings

1 error
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Failed to configure mappings

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwConfigurationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:241)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:244)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.addMappings(TypeMapImpl.java:92)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapStore.getOrCreate(TypeMapStore.java:124)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.addMappings(ModelMapper.java:113)
    at xyz.gigler.cook.AppConfig.modelMapper(AppConfig.java:51)
    at xyz.gigler.cook.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93f5c8e.CGLIB$modelMapper$0(<generated>)
    at xyz.gigler.cook.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93f5c8e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2501590.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at xyz.gigler.cook.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93f5c8e.modelMapper(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at xyz.gigler.cook.AppConfig$4.configure(AppConfig.java:63)
    at org.modelmapper.PropertyMap.configure(PropertyMap.java:389)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ExplicitMappingBuilder.build(ExplicitMappingBuilder.java:227)
    ... 53 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```